# Custom Grand Prix Mario kart 8

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

Is it possible to make custom grand Prixs in Mario kart 8 on the Wii U.

I find it hugely frustrating that they only last 4 rounds. Ideally I'd like to be able to play 12 tracks and ideally the tracks in which are played.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, you can just keep doing versus and selecting a new track.  Similar to how online works and is continuous but no option to customize Grand Prix.

Comment: Thats rubbish though, then we have to manually add up our scores and work who's won... Why don't Nintendo think of adding a little customisation to their games :( Still thanks for thinking up something

Comment: You don't have to manually add your scores - the game will do it for you in VS Mode. See my answer for further explanation of the mode, but if you play 12 races, it will show you the final score from those 12 races (up to 180 points in this case, since 15 points is the max for first place).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are asking by using "VS mode".

In VS mode you can:

*Select how many races there will be (anywhere from 3 to 32)
*Choose to play the levels in order, randomly, or manually pick each one (you select them as you play; picking one, playing it, and then picking the next, etc.)
*Select what kind of race (50cc through 200cc & mirror mode)
*Select the CPU difficulty (Easy/Normal/Hard)
*Select what kind of items are used (or even turn off items if you want)

The only thing you can't select is which characters the CPU will control.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can select how many races you want to do (up to 32 races) and if you want to do them in order, random, or manual pick.

It also allows for other customizations like CPU difficulty, race speed, and item choices.

These are only available under the "Versus" mode, not Grand Prix. It awards a winner and adds up total scores for each race, just like Grand Prix mode.